# Cannot store picture in database(no error messages appear)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, image

Hello I am here yet again with another problem.
As I followed a tutorial I tried to save images to my database. It all worked fine and dandy with no error messages but for some reason the image refuse the get stored. Nothing show up at all!

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not find database!");
mysql_select_db("Image") or die("Could not find database!");

$imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$imageData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
$imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["type"]);

if(substr($imageType,0,5) == "image") {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'blob' VALUES ('','$imageName','$imageData')");
    echo "File uploaded!";
}
else
{
    echo "Only images are allowed!";
}

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Database:
id, name, image:
int(Auto increment), varchar(40), mediumblob(because of the size)

The only odd thing about this is that "file_get_contents" is blacked out(I use notepad++).
Otherwise I don't see whats wrong, I have checked guides and whatnot but the thing is that I need to use this method in another form that have a large amount of information stored(15 fields including a description). I am still very new to this and its hard to know what to keep and how to write the best way. But anyway if you can help me it would be awesome.
If you have any questions regardning anything or just some tips just comment.

Comment: Try not passing an empty string to an auto increment field.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_x()` but MySQLi or PDO. Why do you even want to store images in your database?

Comment: @Musa

So I should change it to serial or?

Comment: @str
I want to store images to my database because its a remote server. I can't save it in a file directory, I would really like to but its to late and would require to much work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name blob should be surrounded by back-ticks, not apostrophes.

However, I recommend that you change the name of this table to something that is not a reserved word in MySQL.

Comment: Agreed on the first point, but the second one is just a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!
It says that I need to wait some minutes until I accept it though. I will as soon as I can!